# rename images and move the renamed images in newly created directory

Tags: php, rename, mkdir

Here i want to create a new directory called c:/xampp/htdocs/haha/tour/ and in the directory i want to move my renamed images .Here ,i managed to create the new directory but can't move and rename my images.How can i solve this problem??

```
$dir='c:/xampp/htdocs/practice/haha';

$i=1;
if(is_dir($dir)){
echo dirname($dir).'</br>';
     $file=opendir($dir);

     while(($data=readdir($file))!==false){
      if($data!='.' && $data!='..'){

            $info=pathinfo($data,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            if(!file_exists($dir.'/tour')){

                    mkdir($dir.'/tour/');

            }

            rename($dir.$data,$dir.'/tour/'.'image '.$i.'.jpg');

            $i++;
         }
      }
     }
```

Comment: So if I got you right you want to take all files (Only images?) from `c:/xampp/htdocs/practice/haha` and move them into `c:/xampp/htdocs/practice/haha/tour/FILE extension/image$i.jpg` ?

Comment: edited my post.Pathinfo() function is removed form rename() function.FIle extension is  omitted in case you didn't notice

Comment: Ah you updated the code :D now I see it so, but you only want to move images? into `c:/xampp/htdocs/practice/haha/tour/image$i.jpg` and all `files/images? from c:/xampp/htdocs/practice/haha` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some `/`:

```
rename($dir.$data,$dir.'/tour/'.'image '.$i.'.jpg');
           ^---
```

`$data` doesn't contain ANY `/`, so what you're building is

```
rename('c:/xampp/htdocs/practice/haha' . 'foo', etc...)
```

which becomes

```
rename('c:/xampp/htdocs/practice/hahafoo', etc...)
                                 ^^^^^^^---doesn't exist
```

Try

```
   rename($dir .'/' . $data,$dir.'/tour/'.'image '.$i.'.jpg');
              ^^^^^^^^
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

Here I just get all images from your directory with [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). I create the directory if it doesn't exist already with [`mkdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) and then move all images
 with [`rename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php).

```
<?php

    $dir = "c:/xampp/htdocs/practice/haha";
    $files = glob($dir . "/*.{jpg,png,gif,jepg}", GLOB_BRACE);


    //Create directory
    if (!file_exists($dir . "/tour")) {
        mkdir($dir . "/tour");         
    } 

    //Move all images
    foreach($files as $key => $file) {
        rename($dir . "/" .$data, $dir . "/tour/image" . ($key+1) . ".jpg");
    }

?>
```